# Big O notation with recursion

Tags: java, big-o

I have a question about the Big O notation of this code:

```
int strange_sumA(int[] arr) {
     if (arr.length == 1) {
        return arr[0];
        } else {
             int newlen = arr.length/2;
             int[] arrLeft = new int[newlen];
             int[] arrRight = new int[newlen];
         for (int i=0; i<newlen; i++) {
             arrLeft[i] = arr[i];
         }
         for (int i=newlen; i<arr.length-1; i++) {
             arrRight[i-newlen] = arr[i];
         }
         return strange_sumA(arrLeft) + strange_sumA(arrRight);
    }
}
```

From what I understand, the first for loop is O(n/2) and the second for loop is O(n/2), making the entire first run O(n). Then, after the first recursion, the big o of the next two recursion will still be O(n) since 2[n/2] = n and the next with be too since 4[n/4] = n. So, will the entire big O notation of this algorithm be O(n^2)? I think the code will run N times but I am not sure

Comment: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2012sp/lectures/lec20-master/lec20.html

Comment: A warning: this will not work as intended for input arrays of odd length. The new "half-arrays" will have *one less* element in total, and the second `for` loop will overstep the `arrRight` array's boundary

Comment: Remember that O(n / 2) and O(n) mean exactly the same thing. It's not technically wrong to say O(n / 2), but it is slightly unusual.

Answer (score 1):

When doing runtime analysis, it is important to think about what it is that you are measuring. For example...It looks like you are summing all of the digits in the array. However, you are not doing it iteratively - You are doing it recursively. So, if your most "expensive" operation (step that takes the most time) is a function call...then you may choose to express run time measured in function calls.

Since you are dividing your array in half every time, then it is logarithmic.

```
O(log n)
```

Now, if you also want to take into account each array operation.

```
arrLeft[i] = arr[i];
```

you do this O(n/2) operation twice, so O(n), for each function call. So each function call has O(n) array operations.

```
O(n)
```

For overall array operations, we must multiply the # of array operations per  function call by the # of total function calls.

```
O(n * log n)
```

You can also prove this via the [master theorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)

Answer (score 0):

Let T(n) be the time complexity of this algorithm with array of length n. So we get:

T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)

T(n) = 2(2T(n/4) + n/2) + O(n)

....

T(n) = 2^(log_2(n))T(1) + log_2(n) * O(n) = O(n) + O(n) * log_2(n) = O(n log n)

Comment: I'm confused where you are getting log from. according to this source, isn't the tree balanced and thus should be O(n^2)?https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2012sp/lectures/lec20-master/lec20.html

Comment: @AlexJustiniano I showed all the steps above to where the log comes from.  Its basically the same thing done by Taoran Xue with all the stuff in the middle

Comment: @AlexJustiniano It is a balanced binary tree. For each level time complexity is O(n) and height of the tree is log n. Therefore total T(n) is O(n log n). I think it would be a better way to understand with tree if you get confused with the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Start with T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n

```
T(n/2) = 2T(n/4) + n/2
```

Substitute this into the original

```
T(n) = 2[2T(n/4) + n/2] + n
T(n) = 2^2T(n/4) + 2n
```

Do it again

```
T(n/4) = 2T(n/8) + n/4
```

Substitute again

```
T(n) = 2^2[2T(n/8) + n/4] + 2n
T(n) = 2^3T(n/8) + 3n
```

You can repeat as much as you want but you will eventually see the pattern

```
T(n) = 2^kT(n/2^k) + kn
```

We want to get to T(1) so set n/2^k = 1 and solve for k

```
n/2^k = 1 then,
lgn = k
```

Now replace lgn for k in the general form

```
T(n) = 2^lgnT(1) + lgn * n

T(n) = n + nlgn
```

nlgn grows faster than n so it is the dominant term.  Thus O(nlgn)